# I keep getting an error when trying to start my discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
    PS C:\Users\netin\Desktop\bot> node .
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032   
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\netin\Desktop\bot\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)       
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\netin\Desktop\bot\index.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\netin\\Desktop\\bot\\index.js' ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome! You need to paste up some code fragments like what is in c:\users\netin\desktop\index.js also maybe mark this with javascript so javascript developers can look at what you have once you paste up some code fragments.

Comment: Also, try doing `npm i discord.js` in the console again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not install discord.js

NPM

```
npm i discord.js
```

Yarn

```
yarn add discord.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install the discord.js npm package.

**NPM**

```
npm install discord.js
```

or

```
npm i discord.js
```

**Yarn**

```
yarn add discord.js
```

***Useful links (References)***

https://discord.js.org/#/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js