# I am trying to open my discord bot . But it shows me this message . I have discord.js installed

Tags: javascript, node.js

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js' ]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=discord+code:+MODULE_NOT_FOUND+requireStack+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Seems you did not successfully install discord https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089723/i-keep-getting-an-error-when-trying-to-start-my-discord-bot

Answer (score 0):

To run a node.js file, you need to have a node.js file. When you attempted to run your index.js file, node couldn't see a file there (that's what the MODULE_NOT_FOUND error means). Did you misplace the file you were supposed to run?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).